# Represent the time complexity of the following recursive algorithm, T(n), as a recurrence equation:

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I am trying to find the time complexity of the following algorithm :

```
int pow_17(int n) {

    if(n==1) 
       return 17;
    if(n>1) 
       return(17 * pow_17(n-1);
}
```

So far this is what I have :

T(n) = c1 + c2 + c3*log17n+1 + c4*17(n-1)

I know this is not correct but can someone please explain how to figure this out? Any help is much appreciated!! Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't the output simply be `17^n`?  This recurrence is seen `n` times and if `n > 1`, we simply keep calling `pow_17` and decreasing `n` by 1 until `n == 1` and at each recursive call, we multiply by 17.

Comment: Where in the world did you get a log term?

Comment: Yes, the output would be that. But how much time would it take the loop to get there? is it still 17^n

Comment: @Adam LOL i dont know...

Comment: If it recurses n times then the complexity is O(n). Looks like someone told you that already!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + c

T(1) = c
T(2) = c+c=2c
T(3) = 2c +c=3c
 ....
T(n) = nc
```

Therefore time complexity is `O(n)`